# Why isn't my ListView's selection changed event being triggered?

Tags: elm

Why isn't my ListView's selection changed event being triggered?

I expect the *selected True* attribute to generate the InputContentType message.

However it doesn't.

```
listview =
    select [ Html.Events.on "change" (Json.Decode.map InputContentType Html.Events.targetValue) ]
        [ option [ value "instructions" ] [ text "Content Type" ]
        , option [ value "Article", selected True ] [ text "Article" ]
        , option [ value "Video" ] [ text "Video" ]
        ]
```

In the actual code that I have (which isn't shown here), I programmatically select an item in my listview based on a value in a textbox. This is done in my view function.

Is there a recommended practice for achieving this?

**Appendix:**

```
type Msg
    = ...
    | InputContentType String
```

Comment: I would suspect there may be something in the virtual dom engine that may be getting in the way, but I would recommend moving that kind of logic to your `update` function anyways. Trying to force a js event by writing html is counterintuitive, and even if it _did_ work, it would only make things harder to maintain and debug. That logic belongs in `update`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have a fixed selection. Since the `selected` attribute is set to always `True` then `"Article"` will always be selected. My suggestion would be to add `selected` to every `option`, and then make the `Bool` contingent on which `option` is currently selected in the moment, information that should be stored in your model.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I actually have that in my code. However, I attempted to simplify the example. The issue existed when I had the structure that you described.